# Required attribute not working using javascript submit

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I make some form different action within different button

```
<form id="form" method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="name" class="form-control" type="text" required>
</form>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="submitForm('<?php echo base_url('order/add');?>')">Submit</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onClick="submitForm('<?php echo base_url('order/print');?>')">Print</button>
```

Javascript

```
function submitForm(action)
{
    document.getElementById('form').action = action;
    document.getElementById('form').submit(

    );
}
```

Then, my required attribute not working. Did I do something wrong? Let me know if there is other solution.
Thanks,

Comment: on which browser/OS are you getting this problem. also please close the input tag and give a name to your form.

Comment: Google Chrome, windows 10

Comment: I don't know exactly where to give a name to my form

Comment: Artificial submitting does not trigger the HTML5 required stuff, meaning your form will submit. Do your checking on the backend anyways, it's more secure.

Comment: use JS Form `validate` function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try bellow code. i hope solve your problem.

```
<html>
  <head>
        <title>Submit</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
                function submitForm(action)
                {
                    document.getElementById('form').action = action;
                    document.getElementById('form').submit(

                    );
                    //alert(document.getElementById('form').action);
                }
        </script>
  </head>
  <body>
        <form id="form" method="get" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input name="name" class="form-control" type="text" required="required">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return submitForm('<?php echo base_url('order/add');?>');" id="submit">Submit</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="return submitForm('<?php echo base_url('order/print');?>');" id="print">Print</button>
        </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This script is the simplest for me. I think the point is different id of the button, and type="submit" inside the form like Răducanu Ionuţ said. By the way, I dont use onclick="return" and still work.

Answer (score 3):

I can't give you a good explanation but you need the submit buttons inside the form.

So if you would have a button like:
`<input type="submit" value="Submit">`,
it will trigger the required attribute.

@Remn If you would still stay on your structure with submit inside a function you could trigger yourself the validation like:

```
if ($("form")[0].checkValidity())
{
   $("form").submit()
}
```

and then do something with inputs that are invalid by passing through each required element ( input is set in code ):

```
$('form :input[required="required"]').each(function()
      {
        if(!this.validity.valid)
        {
            $(this).focus();
            // break
            return false;
        }
    });
```

In the below case the invalid inputs will be focused one by one.

The whole code is:

```
$( function () {
    $("body").on("click", "#trigger", function() {

    if ($("form")[0].checkValidity())
    {
        $("form").submit()
    }

      $('form :input[required="required"]').each(function()
      {
        if(!this.validity.valid)
        {
            $(this).focus();
            // break
            return false;
        }
    });
  });
});
```

Where #trigger is an id I set on the button to submit, you can make your own functions to achieve your goal I just used on().

I hope it helps!

Comment: You read my answer but understood only what you wanted. I said the he needs the submit buttons inside form to trigger REQUIRED inputs validation. Please understand it this time.

Comment: @RohitAilani if you can check my edited answer I gave him a better one this time. I see that you edited one person answer by adding "type="text/javascript""... you are a relief on this earth. And please UNDERSTAND that his problem is not the submit of a form but the VALIDATION of inputs.

Comment: I understand everything and by convention a script tag should have type can you please validate a script tag without the "type="text/javascript"". And about your answer its ok that you explained it better,

Comment: @RohitAilani my last comment with this subject: I affirmed "it will trigger the required attribute." and you said "do you still say that there is no jquery method by which I can trigger the submit" I don t see the relevance, have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

I have test your code by adding Javascript part in Script tag it is working fine. And i tested it on Chrome Windows 10.

```
       <form id="form" method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
           <input name="name" class="form-control" type="text" required>
       </form>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="submitForm('<?php echo base_url('order/add'); ?>')">Submit</button>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onClick="submitForm('<?php echo base_url('order/print'); ?>')">Print</button>
       <script>
         function submitForm(action) {
              document.getElementById('form').action = action;
              document.getElementById('form').submit();
         }
      </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript's `form.submit()` function will cause input validation to be bypassed (according to the HTML specification in [point 4 of the form submission algorithm](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#concept-form-submit)). The only way to trigger HTML input validation is to use a click event on a submit button inside the form, either by the user actually clicking, or in javascript with something like `form.querySelector('input[type="submit"]').click()`.